# stitching aerial images to create a map

Tags: c++, image, dictionary, opencv

I am working on a project to stitch together around 400 high resolution aerial images around 36000x2600 to create a map. I am currently using OpenCV and so far I have obtained the match points between the images. Now I am at a lost in figuring out how to get the matrix transformation of the images so I can begin the stitching process. I have absolutely no background in working with images nor graphics so this is a first time for me. Can I get some advice on how I would approach this?

The images that I received also came with a data sheet showing longitude, latitude, airplane wing angle, altitude, etc. of each image. I am unsure how accurate these data are, but I am wondering if I can use these information to perform the proper matrix transformation that I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to understand the math behind the process or just have an superficial idea of whats going on and just use it?

The regular term for "image snitching" is image alignment. Feed google with it and you'll find tons of sources.

For example, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImgAlign.aspx).

Best regards,

zhengtonic

Comment: If possible, I just want to know the superficial idea and use it. Anyway, I will look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In recent opencv 2.3 release...they implemented a whole process of image stitching. Maybe it is worth looking at.

Comment: The stitching module is only for panoramic stitching.